# How to change date picker date to a NSDate type but with zero seconds

Tags: swift, datepicker, ios9

I have a date picker that returns me a NSdate value. And I want to have a date value of seconds set to 0. I have the code to do it in objective c as

```
NSTimeInterval time = floor([date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] / 60.0) * 60.0;
    return  [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:time];
```

where `date` is the datepicker's date. So how to realise this in swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost identical in Swift:

```
let date = NSDate()
let ti = floor(date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate/60.0) * 60.0
let date1 = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: ti)
```

The same can be achieved with `NSCalendar` methods:

```
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
var date2 : NSDate?
cal.rangeOfUnit(.Minute, startDate: &date2, interval: nil, forDate: date)
```

and this has the great advantage that it can easily be adapted for
larger time units like days, months, etc. which do not have a fixed
length (e.g. a day can have 23, 24, or 25 hours in regions with
daylight saving time).